# integration services custom script reference issues

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I received an .ispac file which I successfully added to vs2019 with Integration Service Wizard project everything fine, but the problem is when I'm opening the custom script for the .dtsx file, some of the Microsoft references have a warning sign on them e.g: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk and Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Proxy, reinstalling the core assemblies nuget does fix the problem but when I save everything and close the script editor upon editing again the same problem persists and I think it prevents SSIS from functioning as intended.

I'm new, I don't know much about Integration Services, I'm getting on track.

Question:

- How to deal with those warning signs ?
- Is there any other problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding nuget package dlls to gac solved this problem.